# Reducing the file size of PDFs generated with CUPS-PDF

Tags: pdf, cups

I use CUPS-PDF to automatically generate PDFs from documents, but the size of the outputted PDFs is astonishingly high (~8 Mb vs ~800 Kb of I file produced by File -> Save as PDF). Any suggestion on how to reduce the file size of the generated PDFs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try changing the quality of the generated PDF. Edit the configuration file /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf and change

-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress
to
-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen

The available options are:

> -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen   (screen-view-only quality, 72 dpi images)
>   -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook    (low quality, 150 dpi images)
>   -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer  (high quality, 300 dpi images)
>   -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress (high quality, color preserving, 300 dpi imgs)
>   -dPDFSETTINGS=/default  (almost identical to /screen)

Answer (score 1):

The above is the best direct solution but a good alternative without losing quality is to convert it to PostScript before and then use Ghostscript to convert it back to pdf!

Best use `pdftops` and not `pdf2ps` - definitely lower file size!

Usage is (that's all you need for the first step):

```
pdftops sourcefile.pdf
```

And the second step is:

```
gs -q -dCompatibilityLevel=1.2 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=targetfile.pdf sourcefile.ps
```